# Lightweight bandpass filter for embedded device (no FFT)

Tags: embedded, filtering, signal-processing

I would like to remove certain frequencies from the discrete dataset (signal sampled by ADC). Sounds simple enough. However, there are certain constrains that make things harder:

- The chip is a 32 bit NXP JN5168, that has hardware multiplication, but no hardware division, no floats support, or any tools whatsoever that make DSP easy. Therefore, FFT-based filters those are so easy to implement on ARM Cortex M chips are a no-go
- Sampling is pretty much set at 1 kHz
- real time and RAM usage is a concern, because there are other tasks that chip is taking care of at the same time.

I tried using well-known high/low pass filters of the form:

```
Filtered Value (L) = Previous Value - k*(Previous Value - Original Value) // LPF
Filtered Value (H) = Original Value - Filtered Value (L) // HPF
```

Unfortunately, even with multiple passes this type of filter does not work as I would like it to work. The raise of the HPF response in the frequency domain always starts at 0, and one only can control the slope there by adjustng `k`. Since the sampling rate can't be changed, that's the only control.

If I want to filter out anything below 120 Hz, and leave 200 Hz untouched, that's not possible with the above filter, which is very good at having sharp cutoffs below 80 Hz (at my sampling rate). If I reduce the cutoff aggressiveness, and make filter work for 120 Hz then 200 Hz are also affected (less, but significantly).

Below you can see a frequency response of the 3 passes of the above-described HPF with k=1/2.
[image]

This does not work for me. I am looking for something different: I am looking for a lightweight filter algorithm suitable for embedded applications that can ideally provide a full or significant  cut at an arbitrary frequency with a steep cutoff line, so that neighboring frequencies are unaffected, or affected insignificantly.

Thanks!

**Edit:** I do not want to transform my signal into the frequency domain, but rather continue working with a cleaned-up signal in the time domain.

**Edit 2:**  Changing the hardware is not an option. There is an already existing product that needs a new feature. That happens. That's life. My job is to find the solution, which I am sure exists.

Comment: you tried hamming, hanning, etc?  look up window functions at wikipedia...(Note: maybe you were talking about cortex-A chips not cortex-M chips?)

Comment: or maybe use the right processor for the job if this is not the right processor, can use another processor and leave this one to do the IoT work...Or use a different lightweight chip for internet access and another for DSP work.  Or find a different IoT chip with a different cpu.

Comment: @old_timer Thanks for the input. I will look into that. As far as changing the chip goes this is not an option: I gotta do the task on an existing hardware.

Comment: @Olaf : At only 1ksps, I  would suggest that it is entirely workable at 32MIPS (from experience).

Comment: @Clifford: I was not only after the CPU speed. OP seems to have RAM constraints, which directly affects the number of taps. After all it depends on the the acceptable parameters. Note that OP shows only highpass, but asks for bandpass.

Comment: Downvoters: please explain why you hit that arrow in terms of what's wrong with the question (or the format)

Comment: @Olaf By no means I assumed that SO is the coding service. I only ask for the suggestion in my question. Please let me know what phrase made you think that I am asking for the code, and I will edit / remove it.

Comment: The close votes must be meaning to move the question to https://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your computational budget can afford 5 multiplications (MACs) per sample (per millisecond at a 1 kHz sample rate), and you can save the past couple samples, you can use a biquad IIR filter.  There is a [cookbook](http://shepazu.github.io/Audio-EQ-Cookbook/audio-eq-cookbook.html) for biquads coefficients.

If you can afford a small multiple of 5 MACs per sample, then you can cascade biquads and get a higher-order IIR filter with an even sharper roll-off or cutoff.  But you may need to use a filter design software package (MatLab, et.al.) to optimize the pole-zero locations of a higher order IIR filter for your specific requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Adapted from [The Scientist and Engineer's Guide to
Digital Signal Processing - Chapter 19: Recursive Filters](http://www.dspguide.com/ch19/3.htm):

```
static const float pi = 3.141592f ;
static const float pi2 = 2.0f * pi ;
static const float s = 48000 ;          // Sample rate

void bandpassFilter( float f_hz,           // Filter centre frequency
                     float bw_hz,          // Filter bandwidth
                     const float *x,       // Pointer to input sample block
                     float *y,             // Pointer to output buffer
                     int n                 // Number of samples in sample block
                )
{
    static float x_2 = 0.0f;                    // delayed x, y samples
    static float x_1 = 0.0f;
    static float y_1 = 0.0f;
    static float y_2 = 0.0f;

    static const float f = f_hz / s ;
    static const float bw = bw_hz / s ;

    static const float R = 1 - (3 * bw) ;

    static const float Rsq = R * R ;
    static const float cosf2 = 2 * cos(pi2 * f) ;

    static const float K = (1 - R * cosf2 + Rsq ) / (2 - cosf2) ;

    static const float a0 = 1.0 - K ;
    static const float a1 = 2 * (K - R) * cosf2 ;
    static const float a2 = Rsq - K ;
    static const float b1 = 2 * R * cosf2 ;
    static const float b2 = -Rsq ;

    for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        // IIR difference equation
        y[i] = a0 * x[i] + a1 * x_1 + a2 * x_2 
                         + b1 * y_1 + b2 * y_2;

        // shift delayed x, y samples
        x_2 = x_1;                             
        x_1 = x[i];
        y_2 = y_1 ;
        y_1 = y[i];
    }
}
```

Since at the end of the loop, the filter state is retained in the static variables `x_1`, `y_1`, `x_2` and `y_2`, the filter may be called repeatedly with any number of samples - one sample at a time or in blocks (more efficient).

The static calculation of the coefficients and use of single precision floating point however makes it reasonably fast even for software floating point, requiring only multiply-add.  The use of software floating point may increase code size somewhat - most significantly in the use of `cos()`, but if your frequency, and bandwidth are not variable, the coefficients may be pre-calculated and hard coded - I have included them in the code for illustration purposes, and because it was real code I had available rather then developed specifically for the question.

If the floating-point remains too resource or time hungry, then a fixed-point implementation is possible.  I have used the same code adapted for fixed-point using [Anthony Williams' fixed point math library](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/news/optimizing-applications-with-fixed-point-arithmetic.html) which uses C++ and extensive operator overloading to allow in most cases a fixed-point implementation simply by replacing `float` with `fixed`.

Comment: Thanks Clifford! I would like to stay away from trigonometric functions if possible, but I should give that a try, especially that you pointed out that this code performed good for you in harsher conditions. I really appreciate the time you spent answering!

Comment: Note that the trig functions used to compute the biquad coefficients can be pulled out of the IIR filter code and pre-computed before compiling the filter function (for your chosen cutoff frequency, etc.).

Comment: All right, I see now. This is also a biquad IIR filter, and the trig stuff before the loop allows calculating coefficients dynamically for wanted parameters if needed. If not needed the coefficients calculation can be passed to a precompiler. Thanks all of you guys!

Comment: @hotpaw2 : the state is retained in the `static` variables `x_1`, `y_1`, `x_2` and `y_2`; there are no glitches.  Apart from the coefficients, this is tested code used in real applications - the coefficients differ because my implementation is band-stop rather then band-pass - both dealt with in the  same cited reference.  My requirement called for bandwidth  changes so the coefficients are calculated at run-time, but they can indeed be calculated offline and hard coded.  I thought it best to post the tested code rather than simplify it, or describe the calculation separately.

Comment: @Zenj : A "precompiler" is probably unnecessary; you could simply use a spreadsheet and transcribe the coefficients manually.  Note that as statics, the complex calculations are performed only on first use.

Comment: I posted the code rather then simply linking to an external page as such pages may not outlive this question on SO, also I don't think just being given the _name_ of a filter is necessarily very helpful to the occasional user of DSP who then may then need to find an implementation in code he can "just use" rather than deal with the theory and maths which most sources are heavy with.

Comment: I have now addressed the comments in the question.  Some parts mentioned in comments have been removed to simplify the text.